# can't create datatable with angular and local json file

Tags: jquery, json, angular, datatables

I'm starting to learn angular. I'm trying to occupy the datatables library that I use in other projects with other languages. By reading the documentation here: https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/with-ajax. But I have not managed to access the information in the static json file.

```
import { Component,  OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dtOptions = {
      ajax: 'data/data.json',
      columns: [{
        title: 'ID',
        data: 'id'
      }, {
        title: 'First name',
        data: 'firstName'
      }, {
        title: 'Last name',
        data: 'lastName'
      }]
    };
  }
}
```

the problem is in the ajax call (I think), but I tried:

```
'./data/data.json'
'..data/data.json'
'data/data.json'
```

html

```
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="row-border hover"></table>
```

Console:

[image]

And many other things but I can not get to the result, it's the first time I spend so much time solving something with this library :(

Comment: Are you using Angular-CLI version 6.0.1?

Comment: 6.0.3 sorry for don't write the version before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation, when using the angular-cli, that file location will not be found at run-time (using the `ng serve` command).

You have to put your json file in the assets folder, and your path should be like this:

```
assets/data/data.json
```

Please check the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Been looking at this issue for a while, thanks for this!